# Partitioning a graph into connected subgraphs with sets of vertices that must be in the same subgraph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a connected, undirected graph G = (V, E), a set S = {S_1, S_2,..., S_n} where each S_i is a subset of V, and a k > 1.  How can I partition V into k subsets such that it is guaranteed that:

1. for each i, every node in S_i is in the same subset
2. each subset represents a connected subgraph of G?

Comment: Belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: is the number `k` fixed beforehand or it depends on the solution ?

Comment: I assume S_i are disjunct? And I guess n>k?

Comment: and are there vertices which do not belong to any S? (if not, your life has just become easier ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Steiner forest problem is, given a weighted graph G = (V, E) and pairs of vertices (s<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>1</sub>), …, (s<sub>m</sub>, t<sub>m</sub>), find the lightest edge-subgraph H of G such that, for all i, vertices s<sub>i</sub> and t<sub>i</sub> belong to the same connected component of H.

The decision version of your problem is essentially the decision version of Steiner forest with unit weights. Unfortunately, this special case is still NP-hard.

The reduction from the special case of Steiner forest to your problem is, given an unweighted instance of Steiner forest and instructions to determine whether there exists a solution of cost at most c, create an instance of your problem with the same graph, k = |V| - c, and, for all i, let S<sub>i</sub> = {s<sub>i</sub>, t<sub>i</sub>}. If there exists a Steiner forest of cost at most c, then the connected components of the forest are your subsets, which number at least |V| - c = k. Conversely, if the instance of your problem has a solution, then we can find a spanning tree within each of your subsets, and the total cost is at most |V| - k = c.

The best approximation ratio known is 2, which won't help you much if k is small. You'll probably have to use branch and bound.

Comment: _Check if each S_i is a connected subgraph (otherwise the problem has no solution)._ Not true: consider the instance V = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and E = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} and S1 = {1, 3} and S2 = {2, 4} and S3 = {5} and k = 2. Neither S1 nor S2 induces a connected subgraph, but the solution {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5}} is valid.

Comment: Your answer looks like the type of theoretical derivation one is looking for in those moments. Problem is just that I don't get it. Where does cost come into play?

Comment: @Nicolas78 The "cost" here is the number of edges in the forest. I probably should have said "total weight" so as not to mix metaphors – CS is lousy about that. The key equation, which holds for forests, is #components + #edges = #vertices. The efficiency of Steiner forest solutions is measured in edges, and the efficiency of solutions to this problem is measured in components (= connected subsets).

Answer (score 0):

Some random observations.
You may not be able to join two S_i, S_j because they do not form a connected subgraph. Since the graph is connected, you can always connect them if you just add enough other S_k - eventually you'll end up with the full graph which is connected by definition. So the connectivity requirement drives you towards merging. The requirement of k subsets however drives you towards keeping things apart. Basically, you have a n^k search space which you can radically prune if you keep track of those conditions. Of course if you have "free" nodes in no S, that changes the game completely.

Yeah well not really an answer, rather a beginning of one. Will post anyhow ;)