# Is it possible to use NDepend to find class partitioning in an OOP language?

Tags: refactoring, resharper, ndepend, automated-refactoring, code-metrics

Fort first let me better explain the context and the problem.

**Context**

We have a big class with dozen of methods; it violates many Software Engineering principles and this is clearly visible through a code metrics measure tool.
See poor cohesion, too many method, and so on.

[image]

**The problem**
When we try to split the class into smaller classes the problem arise with the instance methods. They need to access one or more field / property from the class and it may be useful to put all together the methods which access a specific field / property. The issue is clearly visible when trying to move a bunch of methods to a new class with Resharper → Refactor → Extract Class.[image]

Is it possible to partition the methods and fields which are connected together (have an high cohesion to use code metric terminology)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly we can do something interesting here, but this requires a partition algorithm and I am not sure which one to choose.

The query could look like:

```
// Replace "NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration" with your "Namespace.TypeName"
let type = Application.Types.WithFullName("NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration").Single()
let dicoFields  =  type.Fields
   .ToDictionary(f => f, f => f.MethodsUsingMe.Where(m => m.ParentType == f.ParentType))
let dicoMethods = type.Methods
   .ToDictionary(m => m, m => m.FieldsUsed.Where(f => f.ParentType == m.ParentType))

// The partition algorithm on both dicos here

from pair in dicoFields 
orderby   pair.Value.Count() descending
select new { pair.Key, pair.Value } 

//from pair in dicoMethods 
//orderby   pair.Value.Count() descending
//select new { pair.Key, pair.Value}
```

Does this help moving forward?

[image: NDepend field method partition algorithm]

Comment: Yes, thanks, I will now start from this point and ask in the data science section for getting a step further.

Comment: Great, if you come up with cool formulas pls update the response

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the [answer of @Patrick from NDepend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46037445/196210) team I've made some further investigation arriving to a some theory and some partially solving example.

First, to find also Property used by Methods you should replace FieldsUsed with MembersUsed in the query.

I've wrote two samples:

- In the [first](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/51b0d/2) the alghoritm is working as expected (the partition are not overlapping)
- In the [second](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/51b0d/7) there is an issue (there should be no elements in common)

To understand this partial solution you can look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/51b0d/6) and [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/51b0d/5) :

I've tried to ask for some advice [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420344/finding-the-partitions-of-a-set-which-respect-to-some-rules), and I found out that this is an optimization problem called **Steiner forest** which involves oriented connected **Graph**.

[Partitioning a graph into connected subgraphs with sets of vertices that must be in the same subgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830594/partitioning-a-graph-into-connected-subgraphs-with-sets-of-vertices-that-must-be/6832175#6832175)

See also:

- [Component (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) on Wikipedia
- [Partitioning a graph into connected subgraphs with sets of vertices that must be in the same subgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830594/partitioning-a-graph-into-connected-subgraphs-with-sets-of-vertices-that-must-be)
- [CommunityGraphPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CommunityGraphPlot.html)